# How to load a simple 3d image with java3d

Tags: java, 3d

I want know how to load an image and move it on screen. I know that I can use `textureloader()` to load an image, but I don't know how to display it on the screen.

Can anyone provide some code or a link that can display a texture on the screen?

Comment: If you just want to load an image and display it on screen can't you just use the standard Java graphics (2D) libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Mehdi, take a look at these articles as they will show you what you need to do.

Specifically: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/

This will give you all the tutorials you will need for Java3d

For loading a basic texture and putting it in a scene, look at this tutorial:
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/j3d_tutorial_ch7.pdf

Specifically, go to section 7.2 and it should explain how to do all of that.

Good luck,

Comment: Are you sure? On page 7-8 of the chapter 7, there's a figure showing textures in a scene. There's an example of the code they used to do it aswell.